# Filtering before parsing with lxml

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I plan to use `lxml`to parse a large amount of xml documents (30+ gb). However, I only need to fully parse some of these documents. There are some identifying features of the documents I want such as `<recordtype="2">`. `recordtype` values may span from `1-10`, for example, but I only need `2`. The plan is to first parse all the xml documents just for the identifying information. Then, use something like `pandas` to create a dataframe where each file has this identifying information. After that, filter out the files that match my restrictions and parse them fully. Alternatively, an if statement that if the parameters match, continue to fully parse. I'm guessing the second is less consuming. Is there a more efficient way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) has good documentation on how to extract features from html and xml files.

I would suggest you use xml to extract the data. I do not know the format of your file.

But if you need to use lxml [here](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) is a small doc that also uses BeautifulSoup.

To get you started. After downloading BeautifulSoup

Example:

```
from b4 import BeautifulSoup

data = "file"
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print soup
```

This will show page in format. From then on you will have to extract data depending on the format.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware on general parsing. However, my question is on the quickest way to sort through the files I need to parse. If there are only 10 files in 50 gb of files that match the criteria I set, it may take some time to sort through them. I'm looking for the most efficient way.

Comment: Oh, It was a little unclear. Well if you find an efficient way to sort through large files yourself, please share here it would help me and others. I also use python scripts for scrapping. If I find something I'll surely post here.